# Raspberry PI connection to Matrix LED panel display issue

Tags: led, raspberry-pi-os

I have a Raspberry PI 4B 4GB, we have a Led Panel display (almost like a Matrix panel display), we use to have a Odroid XU4 with Ubuntu running our video display software but it broke, so we want to use the Raspberry PI for this function. So the Odroid worked great but the PI with Raspbian does not work at all, it looks like it boots but pixelated and then just show black with some dots, but if you plug it in to normal LED pc screen it works even with the Led Panel display plugged in and not working I can remote to the PI and still it display 100% but no picture on the LED Panels.
What can I do to fix this?

Comment: you are asking technical questions about an unknown device ... `almost like a Matrix panel display` is not a clear description of the device

Comment: You ask about a matrix panel WITHOUT disclosing any details.... Please take a look again and try to edit your question so you can get help.